# Setting up a store-like url structure in Wordpress with custom taxonomies and terms for a custom post type

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

**Abstract**

I've been tasked to figure out how to use the [Wordpress Rewrite API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API) to create a URL structure that can filter posts of a `products` custom post type. When passing terms of taxonomies through a URL structure Wordpress would natively filter the `products` posts and return the results to the `archive-products.php` template.

**Example data set of `taxonomies` and their `terms` of `products`**

- Solutions

  - Broadband
  - Enterprise
- Series

  - Express
  - Optical Lan
- Industries

  - Business
  - Education
  - Higher Education
  - Healthcare
- Tech

  - Advanced Operations
  - Internet
  - Legacy Services

**Examples of desired URLs**

1. `products/solutions/broadband,enterprise/series/express/industries/business,education`
2. `products/industries/tech/internet/solutions/broadband,express`
3. `products/solutions/broadband`

The above is just an idea for a structure any others are more than welcome.

**Problem**

Due to my lack of regex skills I'm not sure what is possible or not. Any point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Go through the below code. It's may help you.**

```
function generate_taxonomy_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {
  $rules = array();
  $post_types = get_post_types( array( 'name' => 'products', 'public' => true, '_builtin' => false ), 'objects' );
  $taxonomies = get_taxonomies( array( 'name' => 'Solutions', 'public' => true, '_builtin' => false ), 'objects' );

  foreach ( $post_types as $post_type ) {
    $post_type_name = $post_type->name; // 'product'
    $post_type_slug = $post_type->rewrite['slug']; // 'products'

    foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
      if ( $taxonomy->object_type[0] == $post_type_name ) {
        $terms = get_categories( array( 'type' => $post_type_name, 'taxonomy' => $taxonomy->name, 'hide_empty' => 0 ) );
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
          $rules[$post_type_slug . '/' . $term->slug . '/?$'] = 'index.php?' . $term->taxonomy . '=' . $term->slug;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  $wp_rewrite->rules = $rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'generate_taxonomy_rewrite_rules');
```